# Trying to understand how WHERE IN in a subquery works in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata

I'm trying to build a sub-query with a list in the where clause, I have tried several variations and I think the problem is with the way I'm structuring the WHERE IN. Help is grealy appreciated!!

```
SELECT  a.ACCT_SK, 
        a.BTN,
        a.PRODUCT_SET,
        MAX(b.ORD_CREATD_DT)

     FROM MM.MEC_ACCT_ATTR a, CDI_CRM.ORD_MSTR b

     WHERE a.ACCT_SK=b.ACCT_SK AND a.BTN=b.BTN

        (SELECT b.ACCT_SK, b.ORD_CREATD_DT
        FROM  CDI_CRM.ORD_MSTR b
        WHERE b.ACCT_SK IN ('44347714',
        '44023302',
        '43604964'));
```

SELECT Failed. 3706: (-3706)Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'SELECT' keyword

The desired output is a table with Product set for 50 ACCT_SKs with the most recent order date matched on ACCT_SK and BTN.

Comment: The subquery should only return 1 column.

Comment: The subquery can only return one column, and your syntax is not valid.  You need to be comparing something to the result of the sub-query.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve my desired result? I read all about sub-queries last night and thought that might be the way to get what I needed. I remember reading it only returns one row....so that makes sense. How should I be thinking about the problem instead?

Comment: There's no `WHERE IN` in the top Select, just an unrelated #2 Select

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without sample data and desired result.

Comment: Subqueries *can* return multiple columns, e.g. `... where (col1, col2) in (select col1,col2 from ...)`

Comment: Right and I need multiple rows. So joins for sure.

Comment: @dnoeth - holy cow, that works?  Is that an ansi sql thing, or just Teradata?

Comment: @Andrew: It's Standard SQL, but not all DBMSes support it

Answer (score 1):

Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query doesn't make much sense, but I suspect you want:

```
SELECT a.ACCT_SK, a.BTN, a.PRODUCT_SET,
       MAX(o.ORD_CREATD_DT)
FROM MM.MEC_ACCT_ATTR a JOIN
     CDI_CRM.ORD_MSTR o
     ON a.ACCT_SK = o.ACCT_SK AND a.BTN = o.BTN
WHERE a.ACCT_SK IN ('44347714', '44023302', '43604964')
GROUP BY a.ACCT_SK, a.BTN, a.PRODUCT_SET;
```

This returns the columns you want for the three specified accounts.

Notes:

- **Always use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.**  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Your subquery simply makes no sense.  It is not connected to anything else in the query.
- You are using an aggregation function `(MAX())` so your query is an aggregation query and needs a `GROUP BY`.
- Use meaningful table aliases.  `a` makes sense for an accounts table, but `b` does not make sense for an orders table.